C++ Passing Parameters for a Function Pointer that is a Parameter to Another Function?
I want to write Breadth-First Search and Depth-First Search functions for a graph. But these functions should be able to take a function as a parameter so I can pass each node in the graph to the function as I find it in the search. Because some of these functions need parameters of their own, how do I pass those secondary parameters?
Pseudocode Example:
void BreadthFirstSearch(node* n, void (*func)(node*)){
     // do the search stuff
     // run the function on each node
     func(current_node);
}
void SetColor(node* n, color c){ // set color... }
void SetNumber(node* n, int i){ //set number... }

int main(){
    // make the graph...
    // set the color...
    BreadthFirstSearch(n, SetColor, WHERE DO I PUT THE COLOR PARAMETER?);

I have figured out how to pass a function pointer to my search functions, but the function pointer takes no extra arguments, so SetColor(node* n) can change the color of each node its given during the search, but I have to hard code the color into the SetColor function.
Here is a stripped down version of my code so you can see what I'm trying so far:
void BFS(node* n, void (*func)(node*)){
    // make a visited set
    std::set<node*> visited = std::set<node*>();
    // make a frontier queue
    std::queue<node*> frontier = std::queue<node*>();
    frontier.push(n);

    while(!frontier.empty()){
        // get current node from frontier
        node* current = frontier.front();
        frontier.pop();
        // add current node to visited set
        visited.insert(current);
        // get neighbors from current node and add to frontier...
        
        // run the function on the current node
        func(current);
    }
}

void set_color(node* n){
    // hard code the color because I don't know what I'm doing
    n->color = (255, 0, 0);
}

int main(){
    // do stuff
    // run the search with set_color function
    BFS(start_node, set_color);
    // do more stuff
}

I have also tried looking up variadic functions, thinking that I could pass the color parameter as the extra parameters. But I don't understand the variadic function syntax well enough. Might still be part of the solution though.

You could use a std::function parameter for BFS and pass a lambda in that fashion: BFS(start_node, [&](node* n) { set_color(n, predefined_color); }); Or use std::bind (or bind_front / bind_back depending on the version of C++ standard you are going with). Not directly related to your question but I'd expect set_color/set_number to be members of your node struct, not independent functions (both the lambda and the bind can deal with a class method).

set_color and set_number are just examples for now while I'm figuring this out. But I think I got it working by putting the std::function<node*> in the function declaration and putting the lambda [&](node* n, color c = red) { set_color(n, c); } into the function call.

The easiest option is to pass a callback function that is a wrapper around the real function and knows some of the arguments:
int main() {
    // ...
    BFS(start_node, [](node* n) { set_color(n, Color::RED); });
    // ...
}

That will work perfectly fine with a hard-coded color since non-capturing lambdas can be converted to function pointers.
If you want to determine the color dynamically you'll need something more complex than a raw function pointer since capturing lambdas can't be converted to function pointers.  std::function is perhaps the easiest option to use, but it has a runtime overhead that isn't necessarily needed if the function you pass to BFS is known at compile time.
Instead, you can make BFS a function template, and make the callback type a template parameter:
template <typename Func>
void BFS(node* n, Func&& func){
    // ...
    // run the function on the current node
    func(current);
    // ...
}

With that change, you can pass any function-like type to BFS, including a capturing lambda:
int main() {
    // ...
    Color color = get_desired_color();
    BFS(start_node, [color](node* n) { set_color(n, color); });
    // ...
}


Got it working using std::function and a lambda function. I'm not doing anything stringent enough to make the overhead matter. Thanks.

You can pass the extra parameters to BreadthFirstSearch itself and forward them to the function pointer, eg:
template<typename... Args>
void BreadthFirstSearch(node* n, void (*func)(node*, Args&&...), Args&&... args){
     // do the search stuff
     // run the function on each node
     func(current_node, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void SetColor(node* n, color c){ // set color... }

void SetNumber(node* n, int i){ //set number... }

int main(){
    // make the graph...
    // set the color...
    BreadthFirstSearch(n, SetColor, color{255, 0, 0});
    // set the number...
    BreadthFirstSearch(n, SetNumber, 12345);


What you need, is exactly the same with std::thread.
We can pass a function and its parameters to the constructor of std::thread to create a thread object.
template< class F, class... Args >
explicit thread( F&& f, Args&&... args );

This is the declaration of the constructor of std::thread. More detail: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread
It is about template, type deduction and reference collapsing.
This may be kind of difficult for new c++ programmer.
